# Why my foreach loop is not working?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I am trying to run a foreach loop in the following page to get all the items name,price and quantity from the codeigniter cart library.but my foreach loop is not working in the following page?please help.

```
 <?php
    $cdata = $this->cart->contents(); ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Website Payment Standard</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function paypal_submit()
    {

        var actionName='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

        document.forms.frmOrderAutoSubmit.action=actionName;
        document.forms.frmOrderAutoSubmit.submit();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <!--onload="paypal_submit();"-->
    <body onload="paypal_submit();" >
    <form style=" padding:0px;margin:0px;" name="frmOrderAutoSubmit" method="post" >


        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sumon_goran@yahoo.com">

            <?php foreach ($cdata as $v_cdata) { ?>

            <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $v_cdata['qty']; ?> " >
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $v_cdata['name']; ?> " >
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $v_cdata['price']; ?> " >
            <?php } ?>



            <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
            <input TYPE="hidden" name="address_override" value="0">



            <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="<?php echo $billing_address;?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="address2" value="<?php echo $shipping_info->address; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="city" value="<?php echo $shipping_info->city; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="<?php echo $shipping_info->zip_code; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="<?php echo $shipping_info->phone; ?>">



        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: print_r($cdata); what you have got?

Comment: if i add 2 product in my cart i got 2 result in my array, i am sure there is no problem in $cdata.problem is in the foreach loop

Comment: can you add your array data also in your question?

Comment: i got the below result when i echo print_r($cdata)

Comment: Array
(
    [c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b] => Array
        (
            [rowid] => c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
            [id] => 1
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 50000
            [name] => Sony Xperia
            [subtotal] => 50000
        )

    [c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c] => Array
        (
            [rowid] => c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c
            [id] => 2
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 35000
            [name] => Samsung Galaxy
            [subtotal] => 35000
        )

)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php foreach ($cdata as $key=>$v_cdata) { ?>

            <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $v_cdata['qty']; ?> " >
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $v_cdata['name']; ?> " >
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $v_cdata['price']; ?> " >
            <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have given array then it should work. I have tested it with your given data.

you can see live demo here: https://eval.in/88460

```
<?php 
$cdata = array ( 'c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b' =>
array ( 'rowid' => 'c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b ','id' => 1 ,'qty' => 1, 'price' => 50000 ,'name' => 'Sony Xperia', 'subtotal' => 50000 ),
    'c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c' =>
    array ( 'rowid' => 'c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c', 'id' => '2', 'qty' => 1 ,'price' => 35000, 'name' => 'Samsung Galaxy', 'subtotal' => 35000 )
); ?>
<?php foreach ($cdata as $v_cdata) { ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $v_cdata['qty']; ?> " >
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $v_cdata['name']; ?> " >
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $v_cdata['price']; ?> " >
<?php } ?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1 " >
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Sony Xperia " >
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="50000 " >

<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1 " >
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Samsung Galaxy " >
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="35000 " >
```

Comment: Its not working when it redirect in paypal page. if i print_r($cdata), it shows two values, but when it reload in sandbox.paypal page, it shows only one product.don't know why its happening?

Comment: @Sumon: did you inspect your html? i think there will be some problem because you have different input fields with same name.you should have different name for each input field inside same html form

Comment: I couldn't find anyone.which input field can you tell me pls

Comment: You have <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Sony Xperia " > and  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Samsung Galaxy " > in same form with same name(item_name)

Comment: i run a foreach loop thats why those input field names are same.

Comment: yes. you can use array like this: <input type="hidden" name="item_name[]" value="Sony Xperia " >

Comment: Its not working. anyway brother, thanks for your time.